# Android Tab group Activity Show And Hide Bottom Tab

Tags: android, activitygroup

Android Tab group Activity go to next Activity from Previous Activity ..How to Hide The Bottom Tab? And while coming from next Activity to Previous Activity I have to Show the Bottom Tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can maybe just start a new Activity that is not a child from the GroupActivity? Then it will be added in the stack, but won't be in the TabActivity.

Comment: I guess you are doing something like 

startChildActivity(String Id, Intent intent) from your ActivityGroup.

Beside of using the ActivityGroup. Just create an Intent and start it normally:

Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
startActivity(intent); // Do not call the ActivityGroup startChildActivity(...)

Comment: listen ill explain:i have tab group activity inside the tab,tab having 1 to 4 activities..in second activity i need to show this for network available or not,if i have means on problem,else i check network connection(i did that),when i was press the back button means in 2.1 activity,2nd activity haev run automatically..